Deleting rows in mysql table that contain an empty field where more complete rows exist
I have a table which links the IDs of war memorials with the IDs of records of soldiers. It has a unique index based on the combination of the two IDs (sample data below).
I have recently started storing the source of these connections, typically a URL. What I want to do is remove all lines that have no source except those where I still have no source stored.
By way of example
id | memorialId | soldierId | source
1  | 1          | 1         | Source 1
2  | 1          | 1         | Source 2
3  | 1          | 1         |
4  | 2          | 1         | Source 3
5  | 2          | 1         |
6  | 3          | 2         | Source 4
7  | 4          | 3         |
8  | 5          | 4         | Source 1
9  | 5          | 4         | Source 2

This should end up as
memorialId | soldierId | source
id | memorialId | soldierId | source
1  | 1          | 1         | Source 1
2  | 1          | 1         | Source 2
4  | 2          | 1         | Source 3
6  | 3          | 2         | Source 4
7  | 4          | 3         |
8  | 5          | 4         | Source 1
9  | 5          | 4         | Source 2

Line 3 is deleted because there is no source, and lines 1 & 2 have the same connection but with sources; similarly Line 5 because Line 4 has a source for that connection.
Line 6 remains as it is the only line defining that connection.
Line 7 remains for the same reason, even though it has no source.
Lines 8 & 9 are both kept as it's two distinct sources for the same connection - I only want to delete lines where the source is empty.
The closest I have got so far is a query that identifies which lines need to be deleted
SELECT id,memorialId,soldierId,source FROM myTable 
GROUP BY memorialId,soldierId 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND min(source) = '';

This identifies the two lines for deletion, but if I then wrap that in a delete statement like
Delete from 
myTable where exists (select 1 FROM myTable 
GROUP BY memorialId,soldierId 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND min(source) = '');

I get a message saying that I can't update the same table that's in the FROM clause.
I'm probably missing something obvious as I only have basic knwowledge of mysql I'm afraid.

You will need to use it as an implicit temp table try:
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE id IN (SELECT t.id from (select id FROM myTable 
GROUP BY memorialId,soldierId 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND min(source) = '') t
)


Did you test this?

No, but I did notice an error and update it.

This has worked perfectly for me, thank you (I didn't spot this early enough to pick up any version with an error!). 43k rows removed from a 215k row table in 3 seconds

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/subquery-restrictions.html says:

In general, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

But you can do joins in UPDATE and DELETE, and reference the table more than once.
I'd do it this way:
DELETE t1 FROM myTable AS t1
JOIN myTable AS t2 USING (memorialId, soldierId)
WHERE t1.source = '' AND t2.source <> '';

The join is satisfied only if t1 has a blank source, and at least one row t2 does have the same id's and does have a non-blank source.
Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gyyTPJiRmhzWh4gSFgbqA4/0

This worked perfectly, but the other suggestion made just a couple of minutes before also worked. It's a shame that you can't mark multiple answers as accepted! Thanks though, really appreciated
